# Fast power in Go

Tags: beginner, algorithm, integer, go

I just started learning Go. To start playing with it, I've implemented the [fast power algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):

Any suggestions or criticisms regarding the coding style?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    result, ok := fast_power(2, 4)
    if ok != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong", ok)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func fast_power(n uint32, power int) (uint32, error) {

    if power < 0 && math.Floor(float64(power)) == float64(power) {
        return uint32(math.NaN()), errors.New("Power must be a positive integer or zero")
    }

    if power == 0 {
        return 1, nil
    }

    var factor uint32
    var result uint32

    mul := func(v uint32) {
        if result == 0 {
            result = v
        } else {
            result *= v
        }
    }

    for factor = n; power > 0; power, factor = power>>1, factor*factor {
        if power&1 == 1 {
            mul(factor)
        }
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `error` type is returned, then the variable you're assigning it to, usually is called `err` or something similar. An example is shown [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview).

If instead, a `bool` type is returned, which is `true` upon success, then it is called `ok`. An example is shown [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

---

*You* might know that your `fast_power` function doesn't like getting negative power values, but since I can easily compute `5^(-2)`, I'm sure there'll be someone who will try to do so with your function. I suggest you document that as well (by means of comments), and not just by throwing an error.